# WPF How to bind mahapps icon dynamic object to button template style

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mahapps.metro

I would like to set dynamically the icons of a button. As I use the mahapps icons I have something like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Style="{StaticResource AppButton}" Content="Website" Tag="{iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind=Web}"/>
```

and the style/template is

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <StackPanel Name="ButtonGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}">
        <Rectangle Width="48" Height="48" Fill="{Binding Foreground}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{Binding Tag}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Control.Template>
```

and I build the icons via VB.NET through this code:

```
Private Sub ShowAppsTest()

        Dim _style As Style = Me.FindResource("AppButton")

        Test.Children.Clear()
        For Each app As UserApplication In _user.applications

            Dim btn As New MyApplicationButton(app.ApplicationName, app.ApplicationPath, app.ApplicationArgs, app.ApplicationIcon)
            btn.Content = app.ApplicationName & "_test"
            btn.Style = _style
            Dim materialIcon As New PackIconSimpleIcons() With {.Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.Cube, .Width = 48, .Height = 48}
            btn.Tag = materialIcon

            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf launchApp

            Test.Children.Add(btn)

        Next

    End Sub
```

But using the Tag this way is not working (a working static version was suggested by @mm8 in this post [WPF binding mahapps metro icons in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521628/wpf-binding-mahapps-metro-icons-in-template)). 
How can I bind these dynamic objects to the style sheet? Should I use a converter? Or is there another easier way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify the template slightly:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
    <StackPanel Name="ButtonGrid" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}">
        <Rectangle Width="48" Height="48" Fill="{Binding Foreground}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
                    <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" 
                                                    Width="24" Height="24" />
                    </VisualBrush.Visual>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...you can set the `Tag` property to an enumeration value:

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Style="{StaticResource AppButton}" Content="Website" Tag="{x:Static iconPacks:PackIconMaterialKind.Web}" />
```

---

```
Dim btn As New MyApplicationButton(app.ApplicationName, app.ApplicationPath, app.ApplicationArgs, app.ApplicationIcon)
...
btn.Tag = PackIconMaterialKind.Cube
```

Comment: You made my day! Thanks !

Comment: Not working for me. I have copied the style and button from this post, and all I get is a button with "John Doe" with no icons. The binding the iconPacks to the Tag property seems not to work.